# Windows Server 2012 Sharepoint 2013 Active Directory - what are the user limitations?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, windows-server-2012, windows

I was wondering if you guys know if there is any limitation as far as how many users I can have on my sharepoint 2013 site if I'm running server 2012 foundation, I think I saw somewhere that there was a 15 user limit on active directory for 2012 foundation but can't confirm if that will indeed apply to just Active Directory or Sharepoint as well.
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: SharePoint (AFAIK) doesn't have it's own user account database, so SharePoint users would in fact be users from AD and it would stand to reason that the number of SharePoint users is limited to the number of AD users.

Comment: Thanks, your comment plus the answer bellow confirms the 15 active directory user limit that applies to SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 Foundation

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx

> You can use Windows Server 2012 Foundation in either Active Directory® or workgroup environments to create up to 15 user accounts that can access and use the server software. Each user account permits one user, using any device, to access and use your server software with no client access licenses (CALs) required. In the Windows Server 2012 Foundation operating system, you will receive a warning message if you exceed the fifteen-user limit.